# Running full node ( bitcoind ) without private key

Tags: bitcoind

I want to run full Bitcoin node ( via bitcoind ) in a "secured listen-only" fashion, ie if anybody gets access to the server he gets nothing.

At the same time I want to be able to execute RPC calls such as:
- listtransactions  ( to get transactions for my specific wallet )
- gettransaction

Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve this?
No sending should be possible from my wallet, of course.

I assume that using a key -disablewallet won't allow me to use listtransactions rpc call.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add your addresses as "watch only" addresses to the wallet, which means that the private keys are not stored on the server, but the transactions are still listed by the RPC calls. You can then keep your private keys elsewhere, for example on a hardware wallet.

Comment: ok, but how exactly to do it? what rpc call to use / what change in the config / what parameter in command line for bitcoind?

Will definitely look by myself right now, but if you already know it, please tell me..

Comment: Use the `importaddress` RPC, so it never sees the private key

Comment: Hah..Thanks...
I was checking outdated API:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: Will try out :) Hope everything will work..